# The best way to overlay 3D objects on coordinates recognized by Vision

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, apple-vision

I'm trying to render a [3D object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3CP4Aby3yA) at coordinates recognized by the Vision framework. I already know SceneKit, and I want a way to have realistic rendering.

I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate way other than SceneKit.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe forget 3D and just overlay a 2D rectangle? If so, here's an [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-custom-alternative-to-arkit-c07961a38d2a?source=friends_link&sk=ed0c89157da6520e60179f07cb40f911) that I wrote

Comment: I want to make a result like a link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3CP4Aby3yA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the best (and considerably simpler) approach is to use ARKit's [ARFaceAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor) or RealityKit's target [AnchorEntity(.face)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618102/multi-face-detection-in-realitykit/59809624#59809624). Here's no need for Vision.

[SceneKit and RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/high-quality-rendering-realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal/60513052#60513052) allow you to apply a high quality [Physically Based shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124619/how-to-show-metallic-and-transparent-textures-in-scenekit/61130300#61130300) on model's surface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have additional questions. Is it difficult to apply Unity Engine? Are there any related examples or documentation?

Comment: Sorry, I have a minimal experience in Unity. Read Unity documentation.